# How to pass link name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

In the code below I need to pass the link name inorder to do some process in javascript. Now i don't know how to pass this link name in javascript. I tries passing this.value, this.innerHTML but no luck. Please can anyone help with this.

```
<li><a href="#tab6" onclick="hideupdatebutton(this)">Images</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
function hideupdatebutton(el) {
    console.log(el.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tab6" onclick="hideupdatebutton(this)">Images</a></li>
</ul>
```

Or you can pass only text, like so

```js
function hideupdatebutton(name) {
    console.log(name);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tab6" onclick="hideupdatebutton(this.innerHTML)">Images</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of the link by using 'text' property of anchor tag :

```
function hideupdatebutton(obj){
       alert(obj.text);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dw1fuj92/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
href="javascript:foo(this);"
<a href="#" onclick="foo(this)">MyLink</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it difficult for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it. Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer. –